# Sequence product

Tags: sequences-and-series, products

I'm trying to find a closed form expression for the following product:
$f(k) = \prod \limits_{m=1 \\m \neq k}^{N} \frac{1}{1-(\frac{k}{m})^{\alpha/2}}$.

This can be simplified or approximated into: 
 $f(a) = \prod \limits_{m=1}^{N} \frac{1}{1-a \; m^{-\alpha/2}}$.

A hint or an expression for either would be great. A limit when N tends to infinity can also be useful.
Also, it would be helpful if there is any book with tables of products of sequences.

Comment: Sorry for the typo, I corrected the question

Comment: See this page for your last question http://www-elsa.physik.uni-bonn.de/~dieckman/InfProd/InfProd.html

Comment: The condition $m \neq k$ should still be included in the "simplified" form

Comment: thank you Yuriy for the link, I'm looking at it.

Comment: It was very hard to solve the first one, and I found no known formula that deals with an exception in the product

Comment: It is likely there's no closed form. As for the exception, you can simply divide the whole product by the term with $m=k$ and be done with it

Comment: The problem with the exception is that when $m=k$, the term is infinity (dividing by zero).

Comment: Yes, which is why the term is excluded.